# Logging Conventions using Log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I just started looking into Log4j 2.0. Looking at the user guide, it looks like some new things have been implemented that I'm currently a bit confused as to when I should be using. The primary example is Flow Logging.

```java
public class LogTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        logger.entry();
        doTest("value");
        try {
            doTest(null);
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.catching(e);
        }
        logger.exit();
    }

    private static void doTest(final String value) {
        logger.entry();
        if (value == null) {
            final Exception e = new IllegalArgumentException(
                "value must not be null");
            throw logger.throwing(e);
        }
        System.out.println(value);
        logger.exit();
    }
}
```

My question is, am I using the logger.throwing() and logger.catching() in the intended way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that looks correct. Note that if you use `entry()` and `exit()` in many places, the resulting messages are hard to tell apart unless you enable location information in your pattern layout (with %location etc). This has significant performance impact though, so beware.

As for the `catching()` and `throwing()` methods, it may be a matter of taste whether you prefer these methods to `logger.error(throwable);`.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between using logger.error(throwable) and catching() and throwing() methods?

Comment: `catching()` logs at ERROR level but additional sets the `AbstractLogger.CATCHING_MARKER` on the log event. Similarly `throwing()` sets the `AbstractLogger.THROWING_MARKER`. See also https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html